# How to view lists and data frames on screen?

Tags: r

My code

```
m1 <- read.table("mt6.1r1.rf", header = FALSE) 
m2 <- read.table("mt6.1r2.rf", header = FALSE) 
m3 <- read.table("mt6.2r1.rf", header = FALSE) 
m4 <- read.table("mt6.2r2.rf", header = FALSE) 


p1=m1[0]
per1=log10(p1)
ixxr=m1[2]
ixxi=m1[3]

p2=m2[0]
per2=log10(p2)
ixyr=m2[2]
ixyi=m2[3]

p3=m3[0]
per3=log10(p3)
iyxr=m3[2]
iyxi=m3[3]

p4=m4[0]
per4=log10(p4)
iyyr=m4[2]
iyyi=m4[3]

erxx=m1[4]
erxy=m2[4]
eryx=m3[4]
eryy=m4[4]
```

I want to see the numerical content of the data frames(to check the proper input).Getting information in terminal was in this manner

```
> p1
data frame with 0 columns and 20 rows
> per1
data frame with 0 columns and 20 rows
> ixxr
           V2
1  0.00153600
2  0.00204800
3  0.00307200
4  0.00409600
5  0.00614400
6  0.00819200
7  0.01228800
8  0.01638400
9  0.02457600
10 0.03276800
11 0.04915515
12 0.06554019
13 0.09831029
14 0.13108040
15 0.19662060
16 0.26216080
17 0.39344260
18 0.52459010
19 0.78688530
20 1.04918000
> typeof(ixxr)
[1] "list"
> typeof(per1)
[1] "list"
> per1
data frame with 0 columns and 20 rows
```

Why R does not show full content of per1?What is the difference comparing to ixxr?

Comment: What did you expect when you wrote this code? `p1=m1[0]` Are you perhaps an immigrant from a language that uses 0-based indexing.

Comment: @42- Yes,I am.It works fine with m1[1].